# Replacing MATLAB's repmat() with NumPy's np.tile()

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to port the below function for thresholding an image from MATLAB to Python. However I fail to convert the following MATLAB code:

```
maskedRGBImage(repmat(~BW,[1 1 3])) = 0
```

to Python. This code sets all background pixels in the image `maskedRGBImage` where `BW` is `False` to zero.

This is the full MATLAB code:

```
function [BW,maskedRGBImage] = createMask(RGB)    

I = rgb2hsv(RGB);

% Define thresholds for channel 1 based on histogram settings
channel1Min = 0.985;
channel1Max = 0.460;

% Define thresholds for channel 2 based on histogram settings
channel2Min = 0.264;
channel2Max = 1.000;

% Define thresholds for channel 3 based on histogram settings
channel3Min = 0.000;
channel3Max = 1.000;

% Create mask based on chosen histogram thresholds
sliderBW = ( (I(:,:,1) >= channel1Min) | (I(:,:,1) <= channel1Max) ) & ...
    (I(:,:,2) >= channel2Min ) & (I(:,:,2) <= channel2Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,3) >= channel3Min ) & (I(:,:,3) <= channel3Max);
BW = sliderBW;

% Initialize output masked image based on input image.
maskedRGBImage = RGB;

% Set background pixels where BW is false to zero.
maskedRGBImage(repmat(~BW,[1 1 3])) = 0;

end
```

And this is how I have converted the code to Python and NumPy so far:

```
def createMask( image ):
    maskedRGBImage = image
    image = cv2.cvtColor( image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV )

    channel1Min = 0.985;
    channel1Max = 0.460;

    channel2Min = 0.264;
    channel2Max = 1.000;

    channel3Min = 0.000;
    channel3Max = 1.000;

    sliderBW = ((image[:,:,0] >= channel1Min) | (image[:,:,0] <= channel1Max) ) & (image[:,:,1] >= channel2Min ) & (image[:,:,1] <= channel2Max) & (image[:,:,2] >= channel3Min ) & (image[:,:,2] <= channel3Max)
    BW = sliderBW
    maskedRGBImage[(np.array([np.tile(~BW, (1,1)) for i in range(3)]))] = 0
```

I tried to use the `np.tile` function as shown, but this doesn't work and returns the following error in the last line:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes `(1024,768,3)` `(3,1024,768)`

The `maskedRGBImage` has shape `(1024,768,3)`, and `BW` has shape `(1024,768)`, but somehow I fail to convert `BW` to the correct shape. How can I replace MATLAB's `repmat` function with `np.tile` or any other Python function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is how this site works: you have a go at the coding yourself, get stuck, ask specific questions about the exact thing you're stuck at, others give you a hand. It's highly unlikely anyone would do your coding for you.

Comment: @NPE I don't understand why you are saying that, I was converting a piece of code, and got stucked in one line. Then, I tried to get any hint here!

Comment: Please post the code you have so far so that the readers have better context for how you're representing things in your Python code etc, and can offer more precise help.

Comment: @NPE Thank you, I have added it!

Comment: There appears to be some error with the image dimensions: in one case it is `width x height x channels` and in the other it is `channels x width x height`. In what line does this happen? What does `maskedRGBImage.shape` and `image.shape` return?

Comment: @hbaderts It happens in the last line - maskedRGBImage[(np.array([np.tile(~BW, (1,1)) for i in range(3)]))] = 0 . And the return of shape are the same: (1024, 768, 3) (1024, 768, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already write in the comments, the problem is the following line:

```
maskedRGBImage[(np.array([np.tile(~BW, (1,1)) for i in range(3)]))] = 0
```

First, note that `np.tile(~BW, (1, 1))` does nothing at all: [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) is the equivalent of MATLAB's `repmat()`, which repeats the matrix as many times as you specified, that is only once. So you return `~BW`. You can verify that by calling

```
np.all(np.tile(~BW, (1, 1)) == ~BW)
```

which returns `True`, indicating that this really equals `~BW`.

Second, you manually try to re-create the `repmat()` functionality with the list comprehension:

```
np.array([np.tile(~BW, (1,1)) for i in range(3)])
```

However, note that this returns an array of size `(3, 1024, 768)`, while your images have the shape `(1024, 768, 3)`. This is actually what the error message says.

A possible solution is, to remove the list comprehension and use `np.tile` as a `repmat()` replacement. You actually want to call `np.tile` with `(1, 1, 3)` as an argument, tile the input array three times in the third dimension.

While in MATLAB this works out of the box, NumPy requires you to make the input array `BW` in your case three-dimensional, i.e. change it from dimension `(1024, 768)` to `(1024, 768, 1)`. This is done using [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
np.tile(~BW[:, :, np.newaxis], (1, 1, 3))
```

With that indexing the `maskedRGBImage` variable should work fine:

```
maskedRGBImage[np.tile(~BW[:, :, np.newaxis], (1, 1, 3))] = 0
```